# How do I make a custom gradle template?

Tags: gradle

https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates

After much reading in forums, gradle's jira, and githubs, it seems the above plugin is the popular choice for getting maven archetype-like functionality in Gradle.

**It comes with multiple templates to choose from, but how do I make my own?**

Is there a guide or something that can kick start me into making my own template?

I have a setup I made to generate a new application with all the boiler plate pieces my company requires. I was able to generate this from an existing project using maven archetypes. I want to accomplish the same in Gradle so I can also take advantage of the ability to run groovy scripts when the generation occurs.

So far it looks like the only way to do this is to fork that project and make my own plugin with added template files and such.

Comment: did you ever find anything?

Answer (score 1):

Know this is a old question, but there is a wiki page on how to create your own templates:
https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates/wiki/Template-Customization

Comment: latest changes is 2014 . pretty old